# extract table from image to another image by python 3

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

i want to extract table from image **png** and to save this table in another image. 
i have this image :

[image]

I would like to find two images continents tables :

### **## first image :**

[image]
**

## second image :

**

[image]

how can I solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only have to do this a few times then use the mouse to select the tables. if you have to do this more often ask yourself why you don't get that information digitally in the first place. despite that your post is too broad and off-topic. Please read [ask]. you did not even mention what your problem is. loading an image, cropping an image, finding a table in an image`?

Comment: Very simple with Fred Weinhaus's `multicrop` script... http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the question is tagged with `python` and `opencv`, I assume you want a solution using this pipeline. Please have a look at the following solution. Disclaimer: I'm new to Python in general, and specially to the Python API of OpenCV (C++ for the win). Comments, improvements, highlighting Python no-gos are highly welcome!

```py
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('images/B81om.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Convert to gray scale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# Simple threshold
_, thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Morphological closing to improve mask
close = cv2.morphologyEx(255 - thr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))

# Find only outer contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# Save images for large enough contours
areaThr = 3000
i = 0
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if (area > areaThr):
        i = i + 1
        x, y, width, height = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.imwrite('output' + str(i) + '.png', img[y:y+height-1, x:x+width-1])
```

For the given example image, I get the following two output images:

[image: Small table]

[image: Large table]

Comment: how would you recommend for me to get the tables data into a dataframe?